# "Document was sent to the printer" notification pops up for all users of shared printer

Tags: windows-7

I have a small office network, with a Windows 7 box that acts as a printer and file server, and about 9 other Windows 7 clients. Whenever a document is printed to the shared printer by a user in the local network, everyone gets the "document was sent to the printer" popup in their system tray.

Is there a way I can turn this off for everyone? The computers aren't on a domain or group policy, it's just a normal local network.

Comment: Are the print jobs rendering / spooling on the print server, or the clients?

Comment: @CallenL They are being rendered on the client computers. Should I change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each computer should :

- Go into the `Devices and Printers` applet,
- Without double-clicking on the printer, click on the `Print server properties` menu-bar item,
- Select the `Advanced` tab
- Uncheck `Show informational notifications for network printers`
- OK

Comment: You could automate it via a AutoHotkey script, maybe compiled to .exe, to make it "one-click".